# I want a select query result in tabular format like summary report

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008

for examaple

```
           month1  month2 month3  total
district1    5       2      9       16
district2    1       0      11      12
    .
    .

 total        260    150     140    550
```

here final total is not much important. but at least i need to show count per district per month.

```
SELECT Districts_mst.district_name,COUNT(Payments.PaymentId)users ,DATEPART(M,payments.saveon)Month
FROM Payments
JOIN Subsciber ON Payments.SubId =Subsciber.SubId
JOIN districts_mst ON districts_mst.district_id = Subsciber.District
where lang_id=1
group by district_name, DATEPART(M,payments.saveon)
```

which give me list like.....

```
district_name   users   Month 
dist0           1       1 
dist1           1       11 
dist2           3       11 
dist3           1       11 
dist4           3       11 
dist5           1       12 
dist6           1       12
```

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.  Can you show your current query, and what it's results look like?  Also, you may want to check out the page on [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  It gives some good tips on asking questions, which will get you better answers.

Comment: What flavor of sql are you using, this will be done much differently depending on which version you're running.

Comment: @user1072684 how is your table laid out? more information please

Comment: @adam and jadarnel27 i want a tabular result from sql query which will give me summary table as shown in my question. in short i want  details of users (count) for each district per month.

Comment: @Mayur_Vartak What RDBMS do you have? SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc?

Comment: SELECT Districts_mst.district_name,COUNT(Payments.PaymentId)users ,DATEPART(M,payments.saveon)Month
FROM Payments 
  JOIN Subsciber
  ON Payments.SubId =Subsciber.SubId
  JOIN districts_mst
  ON districts_mst.district_id = Subsciber.District
  where lang_id=1
  group by district_name,DATEPART(M,payments.saveon) which give me list like.....district_name users Month
dist0 1 1
dist1 1 11
dist2 3 11
dist3 1 11
dist4  3 11
dist5 1 12
dist6 1 12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 you can handle this task pretty easily with a PIVOT query. The following example relies on getting your data into the following format (which it looks like you have done already):

```
Name        Month    Value
----------  -------  -----
District 1  Month 1     10
District 1  Month 2      5
District 1  Month 3      6
District 2  Month 1      1
District 2  Month 2      2
District 2  Month 3      3
District 3  Month 1      8
District 3  Month 2      6
District 3  Month 3     11
```

If you can do that, then your PIVOT query should look something like this:

```
DECLARE @myTable AS TABLE([Name] VARCHAR(20), [Month] VARCHAR(20), [Value] INT)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('District 1', 'Month 1', 10)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('District 1', 'Month 2', 5)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('District 1', 'Month 3', 6)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('District 2', 'Month 1', 1)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('District 2', 'Month 2', 2)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('District 2', 'Month 3', 3)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('District 3', 'Month 1', 8)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('District 3', 'Month 2', 6)
INSERT INTO @myTable VALUES ('District 3', 'Month 3', 11)

SELECT [Name], [Month 1], [Month 2], [Month 3], [NameTotalValue] AS [Total]
FROM
(
      SELECT [Name], [Month], [Value], 
             SUM([Value]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Name]) as [NameTotalValue] 
      FROM @myTable
    UNION 
      SELECT 'Total', [Month], SUM([Value]), (SELECT SUM([Value]) FROM @myTable)
      FROM @myTable
      GROUP BY [Month]
) t
PIVOT
(
    SUM([Value]) FOR [Month] IN ([Month 1], [Month 2], [Month 3]) 
) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.[Name]
```

In this example, I used the `SUM([Value]) OVER PARTITION` to get the sums for each District, and then I did a UNION to add a totals row to the bottom. The results look like this:

```
Name        Month 1 Month 2 Month 3 Total
----------- ------- ------- ------- -----
District 1       10       5       6    21
District 2        1       2       3     6
District 3        8       6      11    25
Total            19      13      20    52
```

One thing you'll notice about this approach is that you have to know the column names you want at the top of the table ahead of time. That's easy to do if you're setting up the report to run for a full year, but is trickier if the number of columns is going to change. If you're going to allow the users to specify a custom date range (i.e., 07/2011-10/2011 or 06/2011-11/2011), then one way handle that requirement is to build the PIVOT query using dynamic SQL and then execute it with [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

Comment: 1st of all thanks for replying for my query. I have 2 tables district and payments. I am taking district name from one table and payments detail from another table. Now i need same result .. which you give me from one table. I am using these columns  Districts_mst.district_name,COUNT(Payments.PaymentId)users ,DATEPART(M,payments.saveon)Month. So please find result for my query. regards Mayur.

Comment: More on the dynamic column name generation here : http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/andras/archive/2007/09/14/37265.aspx

Comment: thanks nonnb. if you dont mind then will you solved my query in details? I will provide you table structure and format of result...

Comment: Here If I want to search or get listing year wise. So where i have to put condition (where clause) in query? please reply .....