# MSSQL Escape sp_executesql '/' in parameter name

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I know, never add special characters in table column names. It's 1 am and i need to get this done for a meeting tomorrow am.

I am forced to produce a table with the following format:

```
Plant, Part, 01/01/2014, 01/02/2014, 01/03/2014....
01      123     100         123         1234
```

Now, i'm constructing an insert command then executing using the ExecuteNonQuery command in c#.

1) Excel File is loaded and the contents is pulled and parsed into the following stements
2) C# Code: (Building the sql insert)

```
insertCommand.CommandText = "insert into dbo.tbl_SalesForecast ";

//Build parameter list
for (int x = 0; x < 31; x++ )
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[" + colNames[x] + ']' , info[x]);

insertCommand.Connection = connection;
insertCommand.Transaction = transaction;
insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

3) SQL Code produced when ExecuteNonQuery() runs: (it's a mess)

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert into dbo.tbl_SalesForecast ',N'@[Plant] nvarchar(1),@[Part] nvarchar(6),@[06/09/14] nvarchar(1),@[06/16/14] nvarchar(4),@[06/23/14] nvarchar(1),@[06/30/14] nvarchar(1),@[07/07/14] nvarchar(4),@[07/14/14] nvarchar(4),@[07/21/14] nvarchar(4),@[07/28/14] nvarchar(4),@[08/04/14] nvarchar(4),@[08/11/14] nvarchar(4),@[08/18/14] nvarchar(4),@[08/25/14] nvarchar(4),@[09/01/14] nvarchar(4),@[09/08/14] nvarchar(4),@[09/15/14] nvarchar(4),@[09/22/14] nvarchar(4),@[09/29/14] nvarchar(4),@[10/06/14] nvarchar(4),@[10/13/14] nvarchar(1),@[10/20/14] nvarchar(4),@[10/27/14] nvarchar(4),@[11/3/14] nvarchar(4),@[11/10/14] nvarchar(4),@[11/17/14] nvarchar(4),@[11/24/14] nvarchar(4),@[12/01/14] nvarchar(4),@[12/08/14] nvarchar(4),@[12/15/14] nvarchar(4),@[12/22/14] nvarchar(1)',@[Plant]=N'2',@[Part]=N'250019',@[06/09/14]=N'0',@[06/16/14]=N'2500',@[06/23/14]=N'0',@[06/30/14]=N'0',@[07/07/14]=N'1250',@[07/14/14]=N'1250',@[07/21/14]=N'1250',@[07/28/14]=N'1250',@[08/04/14]=N'1250',@[08/11/14]=N'1250',@[08/18/14]=N'1250',@[08/25/14]=N'1250',@[09/01/14]=N'1250',@[09/08/14]=N'1250',@[09/15/14]=N'1250',@[09/22/14]=N'1250',@[09/29/14]=N'1250',@[10/06/14]=N'1250',@[10/13/14]=N'0',@[10/20/14]=N'1250',@[10/27/14]=N'1250',@[11/3/14]=N'1250',@[11/10/14]=N'1250',@[11/17/14]=N'1250',@[11/24/14]=N'1250',@[12/01/14]=N'1250',@[12/08/14]=N'1250',@[12/15/14]=N'1250',@[12/22/14]=N'0'
```

Here's what's happening in SQL Server:

```
Incorrect Syntax near 'Plant'.
```

Here's the line:@[Plant]=N'2'

Thus, all date columns will have this issue. 
Is there a way to escape the slashes?

I don;t have a better way of approaching this atm. any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: did u try it as `[01/01/2014]` for column names? i.e., withing sqr brackets.
 if you use it as a variable change the variable name and insert to table

Comment: Yep, tried [], ''. "". \. @N, i even started praying ._.)

Comment: You are getting error in the variable assignign part or in the insert

Comment: Your parameter names don't have to match the column names.

Comment: Even if you can't change the column names, *parameter* names don't need to match column names, so you should never need to name a *parameter* as `@01/01/2014`. Can you show the complete statement rather than just highlighting the line with the error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321425/i-want-a-select-query-result-in-tabular-format-like-summary-report

this should be something that you looking at.

You need to use a pivot concept to archive it. On the link already provided detail step, do let us know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that use `01_01_2014, 01_02_2014, 01_03_2014` name for your columns.

Or use `[` for assigned value to your column. For Example

```
Insert into YourTable(Plant, Part, [01/01/2014], [01/02/2014], [01/03/2014], ...)
Values (1, 123, 100, 123, 1234, ...)
```

You can't use `[` for parameters name.